# Change color of shiny sliderInput with range

Tags: css, r, shiny

I'd like to change the color of my shiny app sliders using css. It all works fine when I apply the suggestion of the this answer:

[Changing the color of the sliderInput in Shiny walkthrough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30879743/changing-the-color-of-the-sliderinput-in-shiny-walkthrough)

However, as soon as I change the slider to two values with value=range(x,y), the color of both sliders doesn't change anymore.

Here is a minimal example:

```
   library(shiny)
   ui<-shinyUI(fluidPage(
   theme = "bootstrap.css",
   navbarPage("", 
   tabPanel("Diagramm",
   headerPanel("Sliders"),
   sidebarPanel(
   sliderInput("decimal", "Decimal:", 
   min = 0, max = 1, value=range(0.1,0.9),step= 0.1)
   ),
   mainPanel(
   tableOutput("values")
   )
   ))
   ))

   server<-shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  })
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

and the bootstrap.css (located in www folder) is

```
.js-irs-0 .irs-bar {
border-top-color: #d01010;
border-bottom-color: #d01010;
} 

.js-irs-0 .irs-bar-edge {
border-color: #d01010;
}

.js-irs-0 .irs-single, .js-irs-0 .irs-bar-edge, .js-irs-0 .irs-bar {
background: #a00;
}
```

The output gives
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVknh.png), but I want the blue sliders also to be in purple.

Does anyone know how to change the color of both sliders when using a range?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want the following added in as well:

```
.js-irs-0 .irs-to,.js-irs-0 .irs-from
```